# PHP: Better way to get results without array_count_values because it is too slow

Tags: php, arrays, performance, large-files

My script merges 18 files and returns all numbers that occur >=13 times within the merger. I timed my script and array_count_values is so slow it accounts for 80% of the 2.35 sec time. The files are large, 200,000 numbers per file, so the merged array is well over 2 million.

Any ideas how I can kick out the array_count_values function or write it in a better way and still get a return of all numbers that occur >= 13 times in the merged array?

**Note: I shortened code to reflect only 3 files out of 18 to be merged.**

```
for($b=0; $b<1; $b++)
{
    echo $b."\n";
for($a=0; $a<10; $a++)
{

    for($i=0; $i<30; $i++)//30
{
    $linespreset=file_get_contents("/users/history/".$folder."/".$round."/masterspeedrandom_randompick_less13_".$b."_".$a."_".$i.".txt");

    $holdpreset=explode(" ",$linespreset);
    $holdpreset=array_map("trim", $holdpreset);
$print1=file_get_contents('/users/'.$a.'/masterspeed_round3_xxx_'.$holdpreset[0].'.txt');
$print2=file_get_contents('/users/'.$a.'/masterspeed_round3_xxx_'.$holdpreset[1].'.txt');
$print3=file_get_contents('/users/'.$a.'/masterspeed_round3_xxx_'.$holdpreset[2].'.txt');

$healthy = " ";
$yummy   = "_";
$print1= strtr($print1,$healthy,$yummy);
$print2= strtr($print2,$healthy,$yummy);
$print3= strtr($print3,$healthy,$yummy);

$resultround=$print1."\r\n".$print2."\r\n".$print3."\r\n".$print4."\r\n".$print5."\r\n".$print6."\r\n".$print7."\r\n".$print8."\r\n".$print9."\r\n".$print10."\r\n".$print11."\r\n".$print12."\r\n". $print13."\r\n".$print14."\r\n".$print15."\r\n".$print16."\r\n".$print17."\r\n".$print18;

$somearray = str_word_count($resultround, 1, '1234567890:@&_');

$frequency = array_count_values($somearray);

$result = array_filter($frequency, function ($x) { return $x >=13; });

unset($somearray);

}//END OF I
}//END OF A

}//END OF B
```

Comment: You could use `fread` to run over your files and *only* count the things you're interesting in as you see the data fly by. From the code you posted, there is zero reason to keep anything in memory so why even bother building an array; just count.

Comment: A database is out of the question?

Comment: Yeah a database is out of the question because I did have it in a database and it was wa  slower than the current script I have now. I briefly spoke with a database person and they said that with the amount of numbers I have I would need someone with at least 10 years experience to set things up for me.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the reply! I don't understand what you mean by 'just count' with fread. Can you point me in the direction of how I could set something up? Much appreciated.

Comment: A database query will obliterate PHP at this. If yours was slow its because your query was bad

Comment: @miknik My query was bad because I am not an expert at databasing and someone who knows a lot about large databasing told me that I would need someone with 10 years of experience to get it moving at fast speed. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could make a good enough query? Do you have the experience to write it at optimal speed? Writing mysql queries for millions of numbers is NOT TRIVIAL. If you think it is then please be helpful and tell me what a good query would be.

Comment: Index your database properly and you should be able to query a database of 5 million or so rows in under 0.5 seconds

Comment: @miknik the 18 files are not static, they are constantly changing with each call to the mysql database that in turn means I would also have the upload time of getting all that info into the mysql database, that will add heavily to that .5 seconds.

Comment: Surely you only need to put *all* the info in the database once? After that its just a question of updating individual values as they change. What triggers the numbers to change? In essence it sounds like your problem is that you have a large amount of data and you need to be able to run queries on it efficiently. That's exactly what a database is for.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please update your post to explain what it is you're trying to do that you using all these files for, because it is entirely likely there is a much better solution (from a not-code perspective, what are *you* trying to achieve. What are the numbers, where do they come from, etc)

Answer (score 0):

i think the the foreach ist faster but i didnt tested it

```
foreach ($somearray as $somearrayelement) {
    $frequency[$somearrayelementkey]++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to test this now but I am not sure of what is happening in your code snippet...I pasted it where frequency should go but got some call stack errors...can you explain how the snippet works? Thx.